# where do these .less files be loaded from?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

on this website : https://www.ornikar.com/

Some .less files are used to change some presets of bootstrap. when inspecting the navbar for example the color of the navbar is white and processed from a .less file (that's what the browser's css inspector shows)

My big surprise is that, the less files are nowhere to be found from the page's includes or from the imports of some other css files. neither is the less js script included in the main page.

Could someone explain to me how this is possible ?

Comment: [sourcemaps](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/css-preprocessors) - you'll find the sourcemap at the end of the linked css file.

Comment: less can be compiled to css at build time rather than on-the-fly in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could after few days understand where do these files be loaded from.
When you map a css to a set of less files, you have two solutions :

**with a .map file**

this method is generic and the .map file is referenced from within the css file (at the end). The advantage is that you can remove the .map file easily forcing the browser's css inspector to display the references as is in the css file.

**the .map file is directly concatenated within the css file**

The references to the less files are directly inserted at the end of the css file. The use of a .map file is then no longer needed.

---

### More details following these links

devtools : https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

less : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_(stylesheet_language)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Chrome that's a feature to help people who use `less`/`sass`.

To make Chrome show only `.css` you need to delete `.css.map` files

**Update:**

Less files are also fetched
[image: less files]

---

**Update °2** (발렌텐) :

> If there are no map files, the trick is the base64 json
>   at the end of the main stylesheet that includes the mapping directly..

Comment: but this is a remote server, obviously my browser is not fetching any .map files. how could it knows some .less files were present to this specific location ?

Comment: As you can see in the image above ( i've updated my answer ) less filess are also fetched from the remote location

Comment: ok after few days of manipulation, i quite understand how it works. in fact, i couldn't find any map files, but the trick is the base64 json at the end of the main stylesheet that includes the mapping directly.. thanks for your help again.

Comment: @ProgramFOX I rolled your edit back since this update is actually a valuable addition to the answer (more over the update *is* the only correct answer among all that info written around here).

Comment: @seven-phases-max it should be phrased *very* differently then. As is, its just a comment,

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Yes, probably. I guess it would be most ideal if 발렌텐 re-writes his comment as an answer to its own Q.

Comment: @seven-phases-max That would likely be a better solution, yes.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I've provided a personal answer.

Comment: @seven-phases-max I've provided a personal answer, any feedback is well welcomed.

Answer (score -1):

It seems your less files are under the following folder path according to DevTools:

"source/Users/vincent/WORK/ornikar-front/solidstorm/src/less/onk"